# Create P12 keystore for Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, keystore, p12

I need to enable SSL to my Spring boot application, So please guide to create a p12 Keystore using the below files for a Spring boot application.

```
****.crt
****.pem
gd_bundle****.crt
```

Comment: Hi! It's not exactly clear what your question is – could you add some more detail to help people answer it?

Comment: Is your application acting as a server or a client? What is each certificate meant to be used for? I guess the first two are the application's public/private key pair, but what is the third?

Comment: server-side application and 3rd file is certificate bundle file